# How can i get back/fix lost vertices?

Tags: vertices

I'm new to Blender, this is actually my first time. I'm making a handgun (Heckler & Koch P30l) and I lost some important vertices.

[image]

Comment: you can select all these vertices and extrude (E) on Y

Comment: I would delete everything but that large side face, and then solidify.